# Geoserver sld style

Tags: styles, geoserver, sld

I am writing a style using geoserver,
Can I organize SLD like a picture below?

[image: style example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SLD specification allows you to use a [`Graphic` to fill a polygon](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/polygonsymbolizer.html#graphicfill), GeoServer [extends the specification](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#graphic-symbology-in-geoserver) to allow the use of a dynamic expression to give the location of the graphic.

This [blog post](http://blog.geoserver.org/2008/12/08/dynamic-symbolizers-part-1/) gives an example of using a `PointSymboliser` with dynamic graphics. It uses an epsression in the external graphic to generate the image name:

```
<ExternalGraphic>
   <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" 
    xlink:href="http://www.usautoparts.net/bmw/images/states/tn_${STATE_ABBR}.jpg"/>
   <Format>image/gif</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
```